# Can´t use the AcroPDF.dll for global use

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, dll

For my WPF project I created a costum WPF control for PDF Reader. Therefor I included the AcroPDF.dll with Com-Components. It´s included over C:\Programms...Path. And it works fine on my own PC but when i publish the project it doesn´t work because it can´t find the AcroPDF.dll and run the PDF Viewer. I have already included the dll in the ProjectExplorer and set the option to always copy that it will get copied in the Debug folder. This works. But when I try to include the Component again, Visual Studio always shows me the dll with the C:\Prgramms...Path and when i try to select the dll manualy it selects the wrong Path again.
So what can i do, that Visual Studio really selects the dll in the Project and not where the PDF Reader is installed?

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: is the assembly in question in the GAC? https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache

Comment: Never the deploy "the DLL".  You have a prerequisite, your user has to install Adobe Reader himself.

Comment: okey thank you, I solved the problem. Someone just could have told me, that it doesn´t matter what the link for the Component tells. Visual Studio seems so inteligent that when i can´t find the dll with the link then it looks in the project folder if the dll is included there.